# Displaying JSONP Data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am having issues displaying the data that I am getting from the JSONP service on another domain. I have been following the numerous tutorials and guides out there but can not get to the stage of displaying it on the webpage.

What I am trying to do is use javascript to display the returned JSON object on an HTML page.

I can see the JSON object being returned and I can actually view it using Fiddler, but I am just not able to get to the next stage and actually produce it on the page.

I have been following this example [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) more specifically the Twitter explanation and have been trying to adapt it to my own needs.

From what I understand`myCallback`that is at the end of the URL below refers to a function which I have to define.

```
<script src="http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/padraicb.json?count=10&callback=myCallback"></script>

<script>
function myCallback(jsonData) {...}
<script>
```

If I am right so far how do I generically access the `jsonData` and display everything on the page?

Can someone please give me a generic example of how to handle this, with an explanation on what they are doing?

I know this has been asked a 100 times but I just need to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks guys.

Comment: `jsonData` is most likely an object or array. You can read about how to work with objects and arrays in the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FWorking_with_Objects, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Referring_to_Array_Elements

Comment: Hey @Felix Kling I have been looking at your post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json as I relised that it would be an array so have been trying to access it as was explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with the code is that it is *not* making a [JSONP request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) - well, it is, but *not* in an asynchronous fashion! Instead the code is using the result of a request as a "normal" non-dynamic script source target and, by default, *scripts elements load scripts synchronously*.

In this case the posted HTML will result in a *ReferenceError* (check the error console) as `myCallback` has not been defined when the JSONP script source is evaluated. One "fix" would be to put the script with `myCallback` first - at least then it should be called with the data.

To fetch JSONP asynchronously wrt the HTML document, either load the JSONP script element dynamically (such as in "onload") or use a wrapper (e.g. `jQuery.ajax`) to automatically wrap/dispatch the JSONP request. The `async` attribute might also be an option, but it is not universally supported.

Once the data is obtained, then it must be used in a *meaningful* way. I'm not sure what "meaningful" is in context. In any case, the following should display an alert with the data sent back:

```
<!-- ensure the function is defined first -->
<script>
// data is /not/ JSON, just a normal JavaScript value ..
function mycallback(data) {
    // .. and turn the data into a JSON string for display
    // (`debugger` and `console.log` will be more useful for exploring)
    alert(JSON.stringify(data))
}
</script><!-- make sure to use valid HTML -->
<script src="http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/padraicb.json?count=10&callback=mycallback"></script>
```

I've also updated the code to use `mycallback` instead of `myCallback` (note the capitalization differences) because executing the request with `callback=myCallback` resulted in `mycallback(..)` in the response .. which will never invoke a function named `myCallback`. I don't know why the case was collapsed - it's either a bug or a "feature" of the Twitter API.

Comment: Ok I have seen a few examples examples of the URL being written dynamically is this typically prefered or would I be better off using JQuery?

Comment: @Corey I use jQuery because 1) It works and 2) I'm lazy. Some problems are fun to re-solve. To me, this is not one of them. (jQuery is not the only option that wraps JSONP requests.)

Comment: Sorry another quick question you say the **data** is a variable why does it not contain the JSON object?

Comment: @Corey [JSON](http://json.org) is a *textual data representation*, like XML. However, here `data` represents a *real* JavaScript value/object. If it *was* JSON (in a string), then you'd need to do something like: `var data = JSON.parse(jsonData)` to use the data as anything other than a string. But this is not required here as JSONP passes a real JavaScript object (and not the JSON representation of such) to the callback.

Comment: @Corey Look at the response: `mycallback({"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]});` -- that's *real* JavaScript that is executed and is "just a normal function call" passing in a "real JavaScript object". (But I see a problem: it changed `callback=myCallback` to `mycallback(..)`; I've updated my answer accordingly.)

Comment: How are you getting these errors? I have just changed the src script to a lowercase 'c' and now in the firefox developer tools I am getting back data that looks like a string. Otherwise anything else within the other script tags is not run including the alert or anything else that I have in there.

Comment: @Corey Browse to: http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/padraicb.json?count=10&callback=mycallback (or whatever JSONP URL is being used) - what do you get? Does this agree with what you are seeing in the developer tools?

Comment: Oh okay yes it does. Why would the other script not be executed? Is it something to do with the fact that they are both being executed at the same time?

Comment: @Corey Scripts elements that appear in the HTML markup are executed *synchronously* and *in order* (excepting application of the `async` attribute). This is why the "mycallback" script *must* appear first in this situation - because both script elements are in the HTML markup and are thus executed *synchronously* and *in order*.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your patience I really appreciate it!